# replacing interrelative for-loop with apply syntax

Tags: for-loop, apply, sapply

I have a dataset of spectra from three different groups that need to be classified accordingly. Here, a "cleaning" of the spectra should be carried out in advance, whereby the normalized Euclidean distance from the `ALS package`  of the spectra of each group is calculated with the respective median spectrum of the group. Then, a certain threshold can be defined, which which should act as an exclusion criterion.

I only used `for loops` so far in R for this kind of questions, but, since the data is quiet big, I want to speed up the process using the `apply` (and related) function.

For better understanding, I created some data and processed them as I did with my real data.
The MWE looks like this:

```
# simulate data

set.seed(230506)

tmp <- runif(3000, min=-100, max=100)
  
mat <- matrix(data=tmp, ncol=100, byrow=FALSE)
lab <- rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each=NROW(mat)/3)

tmp <- aggregate(mat, list(as.character(lab)), median)
mat.md <- tmp[,-1]

# plot data

par(pty="m")
matplot(t(mat), typ="l", lty=1, col="grey")
matlines(t(mat.md), lty=1, lwd=2)
dev.off()

# find outlier

out <- NULL

for (i in 1:length(levels(as.factor(lab))))
{
  for (j in 1:length(which(as.numeric(factor(lab)) == i)))
  {
    out <- rbind(out, ALS::matchFactor(mat[as.numeric(factor(lab)) == i,][j,], mat.md[i,], type="euclid"))
  }
}

thresh <- 0.5
nout <- which(out <= thresh)

# plot data

par(pty="m")
matplot(t(mat[nout,]), typ="l", lty=1, col="grey")
matlines(t(mat.md), lty=1, lwd=2)
dev.off()

#####

# here, I tried the sapply syntax, but the output was not right ... 
# out.2 <- NULL

# for (i in 1:length(levels(as.factor(lab))))
# {
#   out.2 <- c(out.2, sapply(1:length(levels(as.factor(lab)) == i), function (j) ALS::matchFactor(mat[as.numeric(factor(lab)) == i,][j,], mat.md[i,], type="euclid")))
# }
```

Since the `for loops` are interrelated (i and j), I need help finding a way to combine these in a simular expression for the `apply` syntax.